# TYPE command windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe

I have 10 files like below:

- file1.txt (file content = "i contain text for file1")
- file2.txt (file content = "i contain text for file2")
- file3.txt (file content = "i contain text for file3")

and so on.

I am trying to do a TYPE command like:

```
type file*.txt > OUTPUT.txt
```

this works to output the file contents only. i need output to also have filename for each file.

my output.txt file should look like this:

```
file1.txt = "i contain text for file1" file2.txt = "i contain text for file2" file3.txt = "i contain text for file3"
```

Thank you in advance for your help!